# Preload worker generated by workerize-loader with webpack and vue-cli

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, preload

I have a worker that loads up firebase-firestore and gets some documents when a button is clicked. The worker is generated by workerize-loader and it works perfectly.

But I ran an audit on the webpage with chrome devtools and got a suggestion to preload the worker's javascript file. I do not have a clue on how to get webpack to include the worker as a preloaded/prefetched script during the build.